# Default Settings on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard

I want to know if I can change the default settings on the mac when you start up your mac for the first time, and enter all the information, such as Company Name, Address, Phone number... etc. Does anyone know how to do that, since I need to change my company name and address.

Comment: @Kevin - Please associate your account and use the same OpenId as for SO when logging in to SU. This can be done under the associations tab on your profile. This will relink the question.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a "me" card in the Address Book application that contains your personal information and can be edited at any time. It's identifiable by the person icon instead of the card icon.

[image: "Me" card for SidneySM]

If you don't have a card for yourself in Address book, make one and choose
`Make this My Card` from the `Card` menu.

If you need to change your registration information, you can re-register your computer [on Apple's website](https://register.apple.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I never need this, but I think try to change your contact details in Adressbook. If that not work look in Systempreference in Users or something.

Answer (score 0):

go to the system preferences and select "sharing" - there you can alter some information...

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Apple's website](http://register.apple.com/) and register your product again.